# My Activity class can't find any views within its associated layout file

Tags: android, listview, illegalstateexception, setcontentview

I have an activity. I set the xml layout file via setContentView. This goes fine.

However, when I try a findViewById() or @BindView with Butter Knife I get the error that the required view was not found...

This is my activity class:

```
    @BindView(R.id.listview_restaurants) ListView listView;
    @BindView(R.id.activity_restaurant_list_image) ImageView image;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants;
    private RestaurantListAdapter adapter;
    private User user;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurants_list);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        this.restaurants = ((RestaurantContainer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("restaurants")).getRestaurants();
        this.user = ((UserContainer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user")).getUser();
        this.url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(image);
        adapter = new RestaurantListAdapter(RestaurantListActivity.this, restaurants, user);
        setListView();
    }

    private void setListView() {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                MenuContainer menusContainer = new MenuContainer(restaurants.get(position).getMenus());
                UserContainer userContainer = new UserContainer(user);
                Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantListActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("menus", menusContainer);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("user", userContainer);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is my layout resource file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_restaurant_list_layout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/activity_restaurant_list_image"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/listview_restaurants"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should show the stacktrace.

Comment: For the life of me, I can't get a stacktrace. It just returns null when I use findViewById() and an illegalstateexception when I use butter knife.

Comment: AppCompatImageView can be casted to ImageView?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: If you are getting an exception at runtime, the debug/logcat/monitor view should give you something. Maybe put the full error message in verbatim so we aren't guessing. But you really need the stacktrace, because this is where the ID details are for the IllegalStateException.

Comment: No stacktrace in the monitor. I'll debug trough the application, this is how I got the name of the exception in the first place. Just a sec!

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding project

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
@BindView(R.id.listview_restaurants) ListView listView;
//change ImageView to AppCompatImageView
        @BindView(R.id.activity_restaurant_list_image) AppCompatImageView image; 
        private List<Restaurant> restaurants;
        private RestaurantListAdapter adapter;
        private User user;
        private String url;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurants_list);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);
            this.restaurants = ((RestaurantContainer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("restaurants")).getRestaurants();
            this.user = ((UserContainer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user")).getUser();
            this.url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(image);
            adapter = new RestaurantListAdapter(RestaurantListActivity.this, restaurants, user);
            setListView();
        }

        private void setListView() {
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                    MenuContainer menusContainer = new MenuContainer(restaurants.get(position).getMenus());
                    UserContainer userContainer = new UserContainer(user);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantListActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("menus", menusContainer);
                    intent.putExtra("url", url);
                    intent.putExtra("user", userContainer);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Method :2 
Or replace AppCompatImageView in your xml with ImageView like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_restaurant_list_layout">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/activity_restaurant_list_image"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/listview_restaurants"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code same as you

```
 @BindView(R.id.listview_restaurants) ListView listView;
    @BindView(R.id.activity_restaurant_list_image) ImageView image;
    private List<Restaurant> restaurants;
    private RestaurantListAdapter adapter;
    private User user;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_restaurants_list);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        this.restaurants = ((RestaurantContainer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("restaurants")).getRestaurants();
        this.user = ((UserContainer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user")).getUser();
        this.url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(image);
        adapter = new RestaurantListAdapter(RestaurantListActivity.this, restaurants, user);
        setListView();
    }

    private void setListView() {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                MenuContainer menusContainer = new MenuContainer(restaurants.get(position).getMenus());
                UserContainer userContainer = new UserContainer(user);
                Intent intent = new Intent(RestaurantListActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("menus", menusContainer);
                intent.putExtra("url", url);
                intent.putExtra("user", userContainer);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```